# How can we get the updated props in the same function, in a react functional component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I'm using redux to manage my state. After making an API call, I would update my redux store, the component would receive the updated props from redux and I would handle update the state based on the props.

With class components I currently have a method that does this:

```
onEdit = async () => {
  if(!this.props.item) {
    await this.props.fetchItem();
  }
  this.setState({
    item: this.props.item
  });
}
```

The updated props would be used in the setState.
Here is an example of something similar with a functional component:

```
const Component = (item) => {
  ...
  const onEdit = async () => {
    if(!item) {
      await this.props.fetchItem();
    }
    setState(item) // this doesn't work
  };
  ...
}
```

Obviously the above doesn't work since item uses the same props as before.

I recognize that `useEffect` is probably the solution most people would go for, but I was just wondering if there was a similar solution to the class component method above, since the syntax is very nice.

Comment: Why do you need to save and get the same item in 2 different places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the item into state instead of props, and use `props` as the *parameter* to the `Component` instead of `item`:

```
const Component = (props) => {
  const [item, setItem] = useState();
  const onEdit = () => {
    if(!item) {
      props.fetchItem().then(setItem).catch(handleError);
    }
  };
  // ...
};
```